# jQuery ajax string or array?

Tags: ajax, jquery

```
jQuery('body').on('click','#submit', function(){
    var name = $('input[name=name]').val();
    var email = $('input[name=email]').val();
    var phone = $('input[name=phone]').val();
    var message = $('textarea[name=message]').val();
    var dataString = 'name='+ name +'&email='+ email +'&phone='+ phone +'&message='+ message;

    var isValid = !jQuery('input[name=name],input[name=email],input[name=phone],textarea[name=message]').filter(function() {return !this.value;}).length;
    if (isValid){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/submit.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                d =  jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                d = d.sent;
                if (d == 1){
                    jQuery('input[name=fname], input[name=lname], input[name=email], input[name=phone], textarea[name=message]').val('');
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Empty fields');
    }
});
```

At the moment I use pieces of jQuery like above to collect the `values` of each `input` and `textarea` then send them off to my `submit.php` file.

I'm wondering if there are any better ways of sending off data using `ajax` as I currently send the data off in a string such as

```
var dataString = 'name='+ name +'&email='+ email +'&phone='+ phone +'&message='+ message;
```

Thanks

Comment: Something like this plugin? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/serialize-form-to-json/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an object:

```
var DataObj = JSON.stringify({ name: name , email: email, ... }),
```

That way you can add arrays, lists etc if you need to in the future.

and then the request looks like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/submit.php",
            data: DataObj,
            success: function(data) {
                d =  jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                d = d.sent;
                if (d == 1){
                    jQuery('input[name=fname], input[name=lname], input[name=email], input[name=phone], textarea[name=message]').val('');
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer to send data as objects per Ajax:

```
var data = {
  'name': name,
  'email': email,
  'phone': phone,
  'message': message
}
```

In PHP it can then be easily accessed as an array and you don't need to explode the string.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a javascript object / model.

I.E

var myCustomModel = {
  name: null,
  email: null
}

and then populate and send this object.

or easier, you can [Serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)  your form in one single hit

it would also be way less bloat if you gave your inputs and ID and then request with `$("#idofitem").val();`

Answer (score 0):

You should send data in the key-value pair form in [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) like :

```
var dataString = {
  'name': name,
  'email': email,
  'phone': phone,
  'message': message
} 
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/submit.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
               ......
            }
      });
```